# How many emails can be sent at once with PHPmailer?

Tags: phpmailer, newsletter

Doing a newsletter module for my shop. (using phpMailer) 
have about 20 000 subscribers in the moment.
have 2 questions:

1. how can i test it and do not send emails to all my clients.
   i was thinking to send some test email in a 20000 loop to my email but i guess all these emails can be rejected by my email server (or even maybe by my hosting server during sending process ?) .
2. how many emails (avarage) it is ok to send in one run? im thinking to send all this emails in parts. maybe 2000 in one run?
3. it is connected with the previous questions. When sending emails in parts is it ok to set some Cron job which will checking if we still have some emails to send? Or maybe the admin should press something like 'continue sending' button every time until all emails are sent? Cron seems to be better for admin but the problem is that it would have to run all the time every 1 minnute, even if admin will send newsletters only once a month. Wouldn't it be wasting of hosting usage?  script runnig every 1 inute and checking db table if there are emails to send?